# How to eliminate the extra asterisk shown from the prime factorization output?

Tags: c++, cout, prime-factoring

The following code inputs an integer (n) from the user and outputs the prime decomposition of n. I need to have the following output (as an example), but can't reach it:

Input: `98`

Output: `2*7^2`

The actual wrong output, which has an extra "*" is:

```
2*7^2*
     ^
```

Maybe there is another solution using functions, which I don't know.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, countA = 0, countB = 0;
    cin>>n;
    while(n % 2 == 0)
    {
        n /= 2;
        countA++;
    }
    if(countA == 1)
        cout<<2<<"*";
    else if(countA != 0)
        cout<<2<<"^"<<countA;
    for(int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i + 2)
    {
        while(n % i == 0)
        {
            n /= i;
            countB++;
        }
        if(countB == 1)
            cout<<i<<"*";
        else if(countB != 0)
        cout<<i<<"^"<<countB<<"*";
    }
    if(n > 2)
        cout<<n;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The way I generally handle it (more often in C than C++) is `const char *pad = "";` and then print `pad` before each term, and set `pad = "*";` after printing.  That way, you only print the `*` when there is something before it and something is about to appear after it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had not tried your solution yet because I'm a beginner in programming, but later I'll attempt to do it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you so much for your comment which is a right solution to my answer. You taught me something that I didn't know before. By using this method, now all of the outputs are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one of the possible solutions to my question, according to @Jonathan Leffler's comment is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const char *pad = "";
int main()
{
    int n, countA = 0, countB = 0;
    cin>>n;
    while(n % 2 == 0)
    {
        n /= 2;
        countA++;
    }
    if(countA > 0)
    {
        cout<<pad;   
        cout<<2;     
        if(countA > 1)
        {
            cout<<"^"<<countA;
        }
        pad = "*";
    }
    for(int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i + 2)
    {
        countB = 0;
        while(n % i == 0)
        {
            n /= i;
            countB++;
        }
        if(countB > 0)
        {
            cout<<pad;
            cout<<i;
            if(countB > 1)
            {
                cout<<"^"<<countB;
            }
            pad = "*";
        }
    }
    if(n > 2)
    {
        cout<<pad;
        cout<<n;
        pad = "*";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not resetting `countB` between each divisor. This will give wrong results. Try e.g. 105.

Comment: @nielsen  Oh, that's a great mistake I've made! Thanks a lot. I would be grateful if you could please provide me with the code you refer to because I don't know how to reset `countB` between each divisor.

Comment: Insert `countB = 0;` between `for(int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i + 2) {` and `while(n % i == 0)`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Thank you. Now it's working correctly.

Comment: I edited your code with this update and a simplification of the printing.

Comment: @nielsen Thank you so much. I've approved the edit you offered me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of unconditionally printing it:

```
cout<<i<<"^"<<countB<<"*";
```

You could test if it's the last number. Example (apply everywhere where it's needed):

```
for(int i = 3, end = sqrt(n); i <= end; i = i + 2) {
    // ...
    cout << i << '^' << countB;
    if(i + 2 <= end) cout << '*';
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it as you indicated and now this part of the code works correctly, but appeared another error because I still can't make the right code: `if(countA == 1)
        cout<<2;
    else if(countA != 0){
        cout<<2<<"^"<<countA;`         For example appears output: 100    input: 2^25^2  instead of input: 2^2*5^2

Comment: @Sara You are welcome. That seems to be a separate problem. Please open a new question about that.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused and don't know if I should write another for-loop for the "countA" part to be able to write an end condition?

Comment: Sure. Now I'll create another question.