# How to print the middle asterisk shown from the prime factorization output by setting an end condition?

Tags: c++, cout

The following code inputs an integer (n) from the user and outputs the prime decomposition of n. I'm trying to set an "end" condition for the output of this part of the code but I can't:

```
 if(countA == 1)
        cout<<2;
    else if(countA != 0)
        cout<<2<<"^"<<countA;
```

An example for the correct output is:

Input: `100`

Output: `2^2*5^2`

But what it's printing now is without the middle asterisk (between 2 and 5):

```
2^25^2
```

The entire code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, countA = 0, countB = 0;
    cin>>n;
    while(n % 2 == 0)
    {
        n /= 2;
        countA++;
    }
    if(countA == 1)
        cout<<2;
    else if(countA != 0)
        cout<<2<<"^"<<countA;
    for(int i = 3, end = sqrt(n); i <= end; i = i + 2)
    {
        while(n % i == 0)
        {
            n /= i;
            countB++;
        }
        if(countB == 1)
            cout<<i<<"*";
        else if(countB != 0)
        {
            cout<<i<<"^"<< countB;
            if(!(i + 1 >= end))
                cout<<"*";
        }
    }
    if(n > 2)
        cout<<n;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have to tried to run your program in a debugger and step line by line through your code?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes. It doesn't appear any error while compiling or debugging, but the output graphically doesn't fit what I want because I don't know how to use the "end" in: `if(countA == 1)
        cout<<2;
    else if(countA != 0)
        cout<<2<<"^"<<countA;`

Comment: The debugger doesn't show you errors. The debugger makes it possible to set a breakpoint at the beginning of your code and step line by line through your code to find out why it doesn't  behave as you expect. The debugger is one of the most important and first tools you should learn as a beginner.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Thank you very much. I didn't know the precise function of the debugger and always when I click on the "Debug" icon of Clion, it acts as same as when I click on the "Run" icon (compiles and shows the error of each line). My problem is how to conditionally print the output of `countA` part, like it actually appears in `countB`.

Comment: For conditional execution you can use the if statement.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I need to stop printing the asterisk, when the last number is called out within the "while" loop (I know the end-if condition in the for-loop but not in the while loop). For example: `while(...){...}   if(...){cout<<i<<"*";` by compiling this statement and reaching the final loop, the final printed element is " * " instead of " i " which is what I need.

Comment: On Stackoverflow you ask specific questions. In your question you asked how to conditionally print an asterisk. In your last  comment you asked how to stop printing the last asterisk. _"Fix my code"_ is not a valid question. What exactly is your actual specific programming question?

Comment: @ThomasSablik  Thanks a lot for guiding me to the right way through this website. I'm an absolute beginner in programming and also on Stackoverflow. I'm trying to learn more about the rules of asking a question by reading the user's questions but I'm still not familiar with it.

Comment: @ThomasSablik  About 7 hours ago I asked a question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67243764/how-to-eliminate-the-extra-asterisk-shown-from-the-prime-factorization-output) and while changing my code as a user indicated, that part of my question was resolved, but another error appeared so the user indicated to me that it's better to open a new question. What I asked in my last comment is according to the previous question and for explaining more about what happened with the code. I would be extremely grateful if you could please check my previous question.

Comment: Should your program only work with two different factors or should it support numbers like 300 = 2^2*3*5^2? Why do you have a special case for `2`? Why do you have `countA` and `countB`? You didn't fix the problems described in your previous question, e.g. you're still not resetting `countB`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik  The program should support all kind of numbers. Defining a special case for `2` is for first checking out if the number is divisible by 2 and then if not, continuing with the other prime factors. `countA` is for counting the number of 2's we have and `countB` is for counting the number of the other divisors like 3, 5, 7, etc. Now `countB` in my previous question is reset and the problems in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67243764/how-to-eliminate-the-extra-asterisk-shown-from-the-prime-factorization-output are also fixed.

Comment: In the code you don't reset `countB`. A separate case for 2 is not necessary and only adds more complexity. You should probably remove it and write a generic code.

Comment: The code contains much more serious problems than just a missing asterisk. The program prints `2^23*5^3*7^3` for input `300`. Where does the `7^3` come from? The correct result is `2^2*3*5^2`. The wrong exponent in `5^3` is caused by the missing reset of `countB`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik  You're right, thanks a lot. Because I'm a beginner, it seems difficult for me to make some changes which I don't know how to. So, for now, I think the following code helps me printing the needed output.

Comment: @jabaa  Thank you. In the following code (answer) these mistakes are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const char *pad = "";
int main()
{
    int n, countA = 0, countB = 0;
    cin>>n;
    while(n % 2 == 0)
    {
        n /= 2;
        countA++;
    }
    if(countA > 0)
    {
        cout<<pad;   
        cout<<2;     
        if(countA > 1)
        {
            cout<<"^"<<countA;
        }
        pad = "*";
    }
    for(int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i + 2)
    {
        countB = 0;
        while(n % i == 0)
        {
            n /= i;
            countB++;
        }
        if(countB > 0)
        {
            cout<<pad;
            cout<<i;
            if(countB > 1)
            {
                cout<<"^"<<countB;
            }
            pad = "*";
        }
    }
    if(n > 2)
    {
        cout<<pad;
        cout<<n;
        pad = "*";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely useful. Consider adding a paragraph or two to explain your approach.